# Python script hangs on cursor.execute()

Tags: python, mysql

**I'm a newbie in Python**

I'm debugging an existing script which is as follows,

```
print "Table name: %s " %table_name_r
print "Between: %s " % between

cursor = db.cursor()
print "Total Rows: %s " % cursor.rowcount

cursor.execute("""select contactid,li_url_clean,li_company,complink from """+ table_name_r +""" where li_company is not null and id_auto between """+between)

print "Execution complete"
```

I'm getting the below output,

```
Table name: li_records
Between: 4 and 6
Total Rows: -1
```

I have 2 questions here,

1.) (Resolved) My table `li_records` have 91 rows in it then why I'm getting the rowcount as -1?

2.) Why my script hangs up on `cursor.execute`?

**Question 1 resolved: Like many of you pointed out the reason I'm getting '-1' is because I have not executed the query yet**

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to call cursor.rowcount after cursor.execute()

Comment: @picmate Thanks, this answers my first question but even after I do that my script still hangs up.

Comment: I believe db is a connection object, correct?

Comment: @picmate yes it is the connection object

Comment: Ok, did you tested your query in the server? does it work there and give you the intended results?

Comment: @picmate, I'm using 'Emma' and it becomes un-responsive when I execute this query

Comment: If the query is unresponsive in the client, then it is not a problem in your python code. It is a possible problem in your sql query.

Comment: Could you try without the between clause? Maybe, that could be giving the error, try the integer inequalities for instance.

Comment: @picmate I tried running for a simple query with where clause as 'where id_auto = 1' but still the same results. Do you think this could be because of the application I'm using to perform my MySQL operations? Because I tried to run a simple query 'select * from li_records' on it and the application crashed out

Comment: Ok, I think I can see what's happenging. Both the python code and your client hangs (Python doesn't throw an error according to your description). That means it is a problem with the server (that's my best guess). Or is your table extremely bigger than you think? Because that could be what is happening when you run your queries. They try to fetch all. Try running something like Select * from <your table> limit 10; if that works, then definitely it is the table size.

Comment: @picmate I can see the number of rows of a table but double clicking on it which is 91 but when I manually write the query 'select * from li_records' the application just hangs up. Yes you are right the Python doesn't throw an error or exception because I even tried to enclose it in try-catch and I'm not getting any message. I believe it is the server too.

Comment: you should run Select count(*) from <your table> to get the number of rows. And see whether that is 91. And also try the limit query I told you before; if that runs, we can be fairly confident it is the size.

Comment: @picmate Same result(hangs up), looks like there is something wrong with the installation of 'Emma'. I will try to replace it with SQLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't executed the query yet, so the database doesn't know the amount of rows that will be in the result. See also [the docs on rowcount](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount).

It states:

> As required by the Python DB API Spec, the rowcount attribute “is -1
>   in case no executeXX() has been performed on the cursor [..]

As to why your `execute` method hangs, I don't know. Could you construct the query string outside of the method call like so:

```
query = "select contactid,li_url_clean,li_company,complink from " + table_name_r + " where li_company is not null and id_auto between " + between
cursor.execute(query)
```

If you do it like that, you can also `print` it before executing. That way you can check more easily to see if there's anything wrong with the query.

Comment: Thank you Jasper, I understood the problem with my first question. Like you suggested I'm printing out the query before executing it and it is just like I expected.

Comment: Mmm, and copying the printed query and executing it through sqlite directly gives you the expected results?

Comment: I'm not using sqlite but an alternative called 'Emma', none of my query runs on that application, not even a simple 'select * from tablename' because it crashes up. Do you think this could be the reason?

Comment: I don't know Emma, so I can't comment on any specifics about that. Are you using the built-in sqlite module in Python, in the hopes that Emma has a compatible enough API, or are you using a special Emma module?

I found this on Github: https://github.com/myemma/EmmaPython

Comment: That's a good point but I can't say anything about the module right now because my knowledge in Python is very limited at the moment but I will surely try to find the module and get back to you as soon as I know any details. Thanks

Comment: Haha, sorry. I just discover that what I linked is totally not what you're talking about. I can't find anything named 'Emma' that is even close to a database. Could you provide me with a link?

Comment: It was pre-installed on the system that I'm working on but I guess this is the link which explains what it is and how to install it http://www.ubuntugeek.com/emma-graphical-toolkit-for-mysql-database-developers-and-administrators.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124077/discussion-between-jasper-and-saumil-soni).